# Is there a way to not only take a derivative in terms of many variables, but instead with respect to many variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

In calculus, you can take the derivative of a multi variable function $f(x,y)$, by taking the partial derivative of each variable: $\frac{\partial f} {\partial x}$, and $\frac{\partial f} {\partial y}$. You can also take the “total derivative” of $f(x,y)$ by I believe making a parameter “$t$” and then using this formula: $$\frac{df} {dt} = \frac{\partial f} {\partial x} \cdot \frac{dx} {dt} + \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} \cdot \frac{dy} {dt}$$ is my belief true that in order to do this you need to parameterize $f(x,y)$ into $t$? If so, is there a way to take a total derivative without having to do this and instead end up with a derivative that would look like this: $\frac{df} {d(x,y)}$? If not, where does $t$ come from?

Comment: Yes, there is a total derivative.  It is a linear operator.

Comment: The total derivative seems to be taken with respect to another variable, “t”. I was wondering if in deriving with respect to “t”, you are adding a new variable like a parameter. If so, I was wondering if you could instead take the derivative in terms of both x and y at the same time and it would look like df/d(x,y). Maybe it would use linear algebra for a small d(x,y) vector. I'm not sure